# preprocess views view field find view block name

Tags: views, theming, hooks

I need the to find the block view name so I can add it to the if statement in hook_preprocess_views_view_field in Drupal 8. How would I do this? When I use kint($variables['field']) to find the variables Drupal explodes so I don't even know if the variables exists

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view_field()
 *
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
    //-- I need the to find the view name
    //-- so I can add it to the if statement
    if ($variables['field']->field == 'nid') {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
//gives you views current display - "block_1" or "page_1"
$variables['view']->current_display;

//gives you views id - "recent"
$variables['view']->id();
```